# delete 2 rows 1 Sql statement mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to delete 2 distict rows, but with simular data. 3 colums, 1 is unique, and the other 2 are switched around. I was using something like this but it only delete 1.

```
DELETE FROM Table 
WHERE Column1 = 'a' AND Column2 = 'b' 
   OR column1 = 'b' AND Column2 = 'a'
```

This only deleted one column the statement. Thanks for any help

Comment: How should we know why this happens if you don't provide example data?

Comment: Show the sample data which should be deleted with this query

Comment: Also, add parenthesis to help clarify your meanings, AND and OR might not be working the way you think they are   (Column1='a' and Column2='b') OR (column1='B' and Column2='a')

Comment: You mean "This only deleted one row" right? You SQL is correct, it should delete 2 rows if they really exist, unless you have a delete trigger that causes the second row to fail.

Comment: Did the best answer solved your problem? I doubt, because your query `WHERE Column1 = 'a' AND Column2 = 'b' OR column1 = 'b' AND Column2 = 'a'` is exactly the same as `WHERE (Column1 = 'a' AND Column2 = 'b') OR (column1 = 'b' AND Column2 = 'a')` as was proposed in the best answer. In other words, your query works fine the way you asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL `AND` takes preference over `OR`.

Your `where` clause is interpreted as

```
WHERE (Column1 = 'a') 
  AND (Column2 = 'b' OR column1 = 'b') 
  AND (Column2 = 'a')
```

This is quite likely not what you want and you should (almost) always put the OR'ed tests in parenthesis like so:

```
WHERE (Column1 = 'a' AND Column2 = 'b') 
   OR (column1 = 'b' AND Column2 = 'a')
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html

Comment: "In SQL AND takes preference over OR" - that's correct, but your explanation is wrong. In fact, his `where` clause is correct without parenthesis, as it is the same as `(Column1 = 'a' AND Column2 = 'b') OR (column1 = 'b' AND Column2 = 'a')`